# How to make proper responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently making responsive-design for the website. I've tried many ways to make it great. Unfortunately, it didn't work out for me.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="custom"  >
    <table class="yslygi">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img src="/images/pencil.png" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/images/larry.png" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/images/tools.png" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="/images/clock.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.yslygi tr:first-child td:nth-child(2n+1) {
     width: 150px;
     padding: 20px 0 11px;
}
yslygi {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Responsive-design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WZ6c.png)

Comment: did you try a framework like bootstrap? it comes with columns where you can easily manage your content.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How is it supposed to look on smaller screens? Unless you mention a specific goal you have in mind, this question is too broad.

Comment: It's "lorry" by the way, not "larry".

Comment: Use 12 column Bootstrap Concept for better responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

to make a responsive website, first rule is never user Table layout, instead use div base column layout. If you are new to responsive stuff, I suggest get familiar with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) Framework. It have good community and a great documentation. Get yourself familiar how responsive work and what are basic coding structure you need to follow.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes y good use a framework like bootstrap.. its easy to manage the content but if you want only mantain the HTML as the image use width percentage to keep the proportion on multiple devices

```
Td.arrowImage{width: 10%;}
Td.Image{width: 17%}
Td.img{width: 100%}
.yslygi{width: 100%}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all don't use table, avoid tables when ever you can. [flex is your friend](https://envato.com/blog/css3-flexbox/) when it comes to stuff like this.